# ScriptHookV .NET "IsInBuilding" Property?

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties

I dont know if this is the right section or website to ask this, but my problem is that how can I check if player is inside a building with [ScriptHookV .NET](http://www.gta5-mods.com/tools/scripthookv-net) (GTA V .NET modloader) and Visual Basic.

I tried to look those functions and properties under `Namespace GTA`, but didn't find anything which is relevant to buildings.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from [GTAForums](http://gtaforums.com/topic/809434-vb-how-to-check-if-player-is-inside-a-building-with-scripthookdotnet/).

Answer for **C#**:

```
if (GTA.Native.Function.Call<bool>(GTA.Native.Hash.IS_INTERIOR_SCENE)) {
    'Player is inside building
}
```

and answer for **VB .NET**:

```
If (GTA.Native.Function.Call(Of Boolean)(GTA.Native.Hash.IS_INTERIOR_SCENE)) Then 
    'Player is inside a building
End If
```

Comment: If the answer comes from another site it would be appropriate to link it.